# A debatable delegate-like event notification pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I was left with continuing the code of a senior developer, where I came across a coding pattern that was not only bizarre, but got me curious about a lot of things. The pattern, however, that I spoke about had something like this:

1. There is a `UIViewController` the view  of which has an instance of extended `UIView` attached to it as a subview.
2. This custom `UIView` class has a reference of the above-stated `UIViewController`.
3. There are a series of methods defined within the `UIViewController` that are responsible for handling events at the `UIView`.
4. Since this `UIViewController` exists as a reference, our custom view calls those event-handling methods through this reference!

In such a system of code, what are the memory implications? How is this any different from the delegate pattern? Under what circumstances using this sort of coding okay?

Comment: I don't see that this is any different from the normal delegate pattern.

Comment: Then why go ahead do all those tedious coding of defining and implementing the delegates in our program? Come on, there MUST be something!

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You explained what the code does, and asked how it is different from the delegate pattern. To me, that IS the delegate pattern. What is the question here?

Comment: From what I know, delegate pattern in Objective-C involves defining a protocol, creating a delegate that adheres to this protocol and notifying the helper classes as to what to do with a particular event. However, in this scenario, we have direct reference of the helper method in our object. And we are directly calling the methods of the helper from the object! Isn't this different?

Comment: As far as I know, defining a protocol is optional for delegation. All delegation really boils down to is letting some other object be in charge of certain activities, and the simplest implementation of delegate is just assigning a property on something like a view for its delegate, such as a view controller, so the view can tell the view controller to do something by calling self.delegate...

Comment: "As far as I know, defining a protocol is optional for delegation." Really? Man, this is new for me. Why are we, then, defining protocols all over the place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60349/discussion-between-mike-and-codingvoldemort).

Comment: It's quite common (in fact, the norm) for a ViewController itself to implement the delegate protocol for an object it manages.  Further, if the two classes connected by a delegate relationship are "tightly coupled" (in the sense that both are written and maintained by a single small team) then it's perfectly legitimate to forgo defining a protocol and just use the class interface.  Protocols are used (in the delegate pattern) to "decouple" the pieces, maintenance-wise, and hence are unnecessary if such decoupling is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this pattern is a little curious, I would hesitate to condemn this without more information about what this child view is doing and what it needs to inform the view controller about. There is, admittedly, a faint code smell here, and if I were to hazard a guess, I'd bet that this view is likely doing stuff that one would now generally put in a view controller.

Often, when adding a subview that has any significant complexity (or is likely to be reused in different views), one would consider an iOS 5 feature, "view controller containment" (see the [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) section of the *View Controller Programming Guide* or WWDC 2011 video [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)).

If using storyboards, you can achieve much of this using the special "Container View" control introduced with iOS 6, found in Interface Builder's "Object Library" (in the bottom of the right panel in the standard Xcode layout). If doing this programmatically, just make sure to call the appropriate methods listed in the "Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container" section of the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW86).

When using view controller containment, you have a parent view controller (the main view controller) and the child view controller (the view controller that is managing the subview). And in this scenario, it's very common to design a custom protocol by which a child view controller notifies its parent view controller of particular events. But rather than adding your own custom `delegate` property, you can use the built-in `parentViewController` property which is automatically populated when you adopt the above "view controller containment" pattern.

Having said all of this, I might let practical concerns drive whether the existing code base needs to be refactored or not. Perhaps the code predates iOS 5, but is a solid implementation of what we might have done back in the day. Bottom line, if it works, is otherwise well written, and has the delineation of responsibilities clearly defined, you might decide to just leave well enough alone. And if it's a little ambiguous (as the absence of a discussion of a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW1) might suggest), perhaps just start by introducing a formal protocol between the child view and the view controller to make the interface explicit. Whether a more radical refactoring of the code (to use something like view controller containment) is called for is hard for us to advise on the basis of the limited information provided thus far.